# one time password in j2me application

Tags: java-me, midp

I am working on an j2me application, where the users can set password only once and it should be the password through out the application life.

It is not password for each user, it is password of application, where I need to store only once.

How to set this password using database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will your database be on the phone? If so, you can use a RecordStore. A good article on it is http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/databasemap/

You can use a Simple Object Mapping to store your users login and password like:

```
    class User {
      private String login, password;

      // ... constructors, setters and getters

      public byte[] toByteArray() throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream( bout );

        dout.writeUTF( login );
        dout.writeUTF( password );

        dout.close();

        return bout.toByteArray();
      }

      // fromByteArray method
    }
```

For each new user you add a new entry to the RecordStore, but never changes or delete content from the RecordStore.

**Update** after comments.

You can use another Simple Object Mapping to store your application password like:

```
    class ApplicationPassword {
      private String password;

      // ... constructors, setter and getter

      public byte[] toByteArray() throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream( bout );

        dout.writeUTF( password );

        dout.close();

        return bout.toByteArray();
      }

      // fromByteArray method
    }
```

You must write the returned byte array at your RecordStore only if the recordstore was just created.

Comment: it is not password for each user it is password of application, where i need to store only once in the RecordStore. Thanks for your time!!